# mouse press projection (c++ openGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, touch, glut

I'm making a simple tutorial game with openGL and have a question about touch method. Please checkout my code:

My (0,0) point is in center of a screen:

```
void Init()
{
    glClearColor(0.3,0.3,0.3,0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glOrtho(-400.0,400.0,-300.0,300.0,0,1.0); //сетка, середина в точке 0
}
```

Before this i'm call mouse methods:

```
glutPassiveMotionFunc(Mouse);
glutMouseFunc(MousePress);
```

And in method MousePress when touch is coming, it's another system coordinate with (0,0) point in top left corner of a screen. Please can you tell me better approach then make something like x-300;y-400 in MousePress method.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `gluUnproject()`? I can't provide a link now, my connection is somewhat erratic :-(

Comment: thanks, i will look at function, but for a moment i think best approach is here :/
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13299602/2204866

Thokra, i'm trying to make drag-control for texture, take a texture and move by calling mouse method.

Comment: You could/should also take a look at a similar question I once asked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244678/3d-ray-picking-use-mouse-coordinates-when-mouse-isnt-locked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the simpler orthographic projection, your *"x-300;y-400"* is the correct approach, although you might want to do some scaling too...

```
float x = mouseX/(float)windowWidth;
float y = 1.0f - mouseY/(float)windowHeight; //flip since y=0 is at the top

//x and y are now 0 to 1, bottom left to top right

x = left + x * (right - left);
y = bottom + y * (top - bottom);

//x and y are now in 3D coordinates
```

Here, left/right/bottom/top are from glOrtho, which in your case can be substituted as follows (but of course storing in a variable is better)...

```
x = -400 + x * (400 - (-400));
y = -300 + y * (300 - (-300));
```

If you were using a perspective projection it gets a bit more complicated, as I've described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20143963/1888983).

[*EDIT*]
Assuming the window size is 800x600, the above cancels to `{x-400,300-y}`. For example,

```
mouseY = 50;
windowHeight = 600;
float y = 1.0f - (50/(float)600); //1.0 - 0.08333 = 0.91667
y = -300 + y * (300 - (-300)); //-300 + 0.91667 * 600 = 250, also 300-50
```

Comment: Thanks!i'am using simple projection and first of all i want to try gluUnproject(); as i understand, that's method specially for this and then simple approach with numbers.
btw as i understand for me it will be 
X = x - 400;
Y = 300 - y;
because i need in points, but in my coordinate system with (0,0) in center)

Comment: @gronzzz Assuming you have an `800x600` window then the above code actually cancels to exactly that. `gluUnproject` will work just fine, but as you say, it's pretty straight forward to do it yourself with an orthographic projection too.

Comment: sorry my stupid, but why cancels ? touch y in 50, so touch in my coordinate system will 300 - 50 = 250, and that's right point, touch y in 450 will give me -150 as i need… so i needn't values between -1 to 1, i need points in my coordinate system. sry again if i stupid

Comment: @gronzzz see the edit. It cancels because first you divide by the window width/height and then multiply by the projection width/height, which are the same.